# Joomla: "preview" K2 item in other language

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am developing a Joomla website based on K2 with a multilingual front end editing possibility. This all works nicely, except for one thing: previewing K2 items in another language than you are using to edit them.

For example:

- When Joomla is set to Dutch, I can edit the English item without a problem. However, I cannot view this item directly without first selecting 'English' as language for the site, otherwise the direct link to the item doesn't work.
- I managed to work around this by modifying the getData() function in the K2ModelItem, so that the language is not checked there anymore. However, Joomla is still set to Dutch, it is not a 'real' preview of what the item would look like.

Therefore, I am looking for a solution to temporarily switch the language of Joomla to the language of the item (English in this example) AND switch it back directly, to be able to continue editing in Dutch after viewing the preview. Do you think this is possible? What code would I need to implement this automatic switching?

Let me know if I need to provide more information. Maybe someone has an inventive solution, thanks.

[edit]
It seems that forcing the $lang parameter in the item URL does a good job, together with the modification in K2ModelItem I described. But this only works with SEF disabled. I'd like to hear if there are other suggestions.

Comment: What are you using to switch languages. As in are you using something like JoomFish?